# Is the ideal generated by $a$ simply $\{ au\mid u\in R, a\in I \}$ ($R$ is a ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

More specifically, $R$ is a commutative ring.

I'm trying to understand what the ideal "generated by $a$" is, where $a$ is an element of $R$. I believe this ideal is simply the set $\{a\cdot u\mid  u\in R \}$

(I'd like to say the ideal is just all "multiples" of $a$ but am not sure whether that'd be correct).

Can anyone confirm or deny that what I'm thinking is right?

Comment: What is $I$ in your title?

Comment: If your ring has identity, yes.  If not, no.

Comment: @Bernard My bad, it refers to the ideal I'm talking about

Comment: @rschwieb Don't all rings have both an additive and multiplicative identity?

Comment: @JamesRonald Requiring a multiplicative identity is not absolute, but additive identity is, of course.

Comment: I thin it's a convention for commutative rings, and anyway, any ring can be embedded in a ring with a multiplicative unit.

Comment: @rschwieb Doesn't the second bullet under the 2. point here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration say that there must be a multiplicative identity? Don't mean to argue, this is just going to subvert my understanding if it's not correct lol

Comment: @JamesRonald What it means is that that is the convention used by Wikipedia, and they discuss rings without identity separately. Some authors say rings don’t necessarily have identity, and that rings with identity are a special case.  Yes, identity is often assumed, and most people prefer to work with rings with identity , so that convention is more common.

Comment: @JamesRonald You can find carefully developed texts by Nathan Jacobson that develop ring theory without requiring identity. They are very interesting, and do have applications.

Comment: @rschwieb I see, I had no idea and I'll have to take a look at those sort of rings sometime, thank you!

Comment: @JamesRonald no prob;emo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, assuming your ring is commutative with unit. As a consequence, $aR$ is one of the common notations for the ideal generated by $a$, alongside $\langle a\rangle$ and $(a)$. "All multiples of $a$" isn't really wrong to say either, but no one says it because "the ideal generated by $a$" has become conventional and universal.

If $R$ doesn't have a unit, then $aR = \{a\cdot r\mid r\in R\}$ doesn't necessarily contain $a$, so it is not the ideal you're looking for. For instance, in the ring $R = 2\Bbb Z$ of even integers, "all multiples of $2$" will be the ring $4\Bbb Z$, which doesn't contain $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just one question: don't all rings contain a multiplicative identity (typically denoted $1$) which is always a unit? (And $2\mathbb{Z}$ would not be a ring because it doesn't have $1$?) I'm sure I'm wrong, just not sure why

Comment: @JamesRonald That's a matter of convention. Some people don't require rings to have 1. For instance, my first algebra book (Abstract Algebra by Fraleigh) didn't require a unit. I personally only came to appreciate the stricter convention at a later stage (when studying Atiyah-MacDonald).

Comment: Ah okay, that's really interesting. Thank you for the help!